# Prevent submit of a form that is loaded via ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a jquery ajax call that load a form inside a div and I want to prevent submit of this form but if I use jquery submit function with

```
$("form").submit(function(e){
  e.preventDefault(e);
  alert('submit intercept');
});
```

It does not work if I place in a external js file but works if I put in a script tag after the form that loaded via ajax call.

Comment: Yes, you can attach event listeners only to existing elements. "Event delegation" is your keyword when searching ...

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$(document)` selector and `on()` method for elements that are dynamically generated:

```
$(document).on('submit', 'form', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert('submit intercept');
});
```

Comment: this works perfect, thanks.

Comment: Glad to help you

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use submit.

Instead, You can try this:

```
$('#submit-button').on('click', function() {
    var userId = $('#user-id').val();
    var content = $('#content').val();
    $.ajax({
        type : 'post', 
        url :'url',
        processData : false,
        cache : false,
        contentType : false,
        data : {
            'userId' : userId,
            'content' : content
        },
        dataType : 'json',
        success:function(result){
            alert('success!');
            var userId = $('#user-id').empty();
            var content = $('#content').empty();
        },
        error:function(e){
            console.log(JSON.stringify(e));
        }
    });
});
```

However, you don't need 'form' tag anymore. Since if submit it the page changes, if you want to use ajax, which is asynchronous should not change the page.

Comment: I can't modify form because it's a part of a CMS

Comment: You should always hook to the submit event where possible. It's better semantically. You should also always use a `form` element, even when making an AJAX request as it's essential for accessibility reasons.